# Opengl Alpha Blending not working?

Tags: java, opengl, transparency, lwjgl, alphablending

In my Opengl Application (lwjgl) I enabled alpha blending like this:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The result, when drawing two gradient circles, looks like this:

[image]

How can this be? (The black overlap is transparency actually...)

Comment: Which of the two circles did you draw first? When blending, you need to render your geometry back to front.

Comment: how can i do this? 
The one who is "over the other" is the one rendert first.

Comment: You need to sort your objects by their depth, and then draw them back to front. I wrote a lengthy overview on various approaches for rendering transparency in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280692/opengl-es2-alpha-test-problems/23283256#23283256.

Comment: Do gradient circles use texture?

Comment: no. im calculating them in the fragment shader, like this:

color = vec4(red, green, blue, (1.0 - distanceTo00 / 1.0))

Comment: Err, what is the point of dividing `distanceTo00` (or anything for that matter) by a constant **1.0**? In any case, you need to draw the sphere in the back first.

Comment: Err, the thing is I want to have a gradient? ^^ 1.0 is the radius of the sphere.

Comment: @T_01: That does not change the fact that division by **1.0** does absolutely nothing.

Comment: yes, but its the radius of the sphere xD 
It's just against the effect, if i see this code in 10 years and ask, "shit, what was im doing here..", like this i know i divide through the circles radius,

Comment: By the way, i couldnt fix it yet..

Answer (score 0):

I had sort of the same problem, try `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)` if all your vertices are on the same plane.