# Should opaque objects always be rendered before alpha test objects?

Tags: graphics, rendering, direct3d

From the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/mistercteam/dx11-performancereloaded)(Page 32)

> Ideal rendering order:
>
> - Opaque first, then alpha test

Why is it? Provided that I have an almost flat terrain and lots of grasses on it, rendering grasses before terrain can take the advantage of Early Z to cull a lot of pixels of terrain to shade.

Comment: In short: draw order matters for alpha-blending. If you are using additive blending, then it isn't as big a deal.

Answer (score 1):

Scene with Transparent polygons should be rendered in Z-sorted order from the most far to the closest (in respect to camera view direction).

Alpha channel is used usually for modulating transparency strength in which case your statement is **not true** as alpha test polygons may be transparent too.

In some cases is alpha channel used as a mask (for sprites or fonts for example) and rendered polygons are not transparent at all. In that case the statement **is true** (up to a point which depends on your scene organization and rendering pipeline).

For more info see

- [OpenGL How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214)