# Order of translucent object rendering

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

When rendering a translucent object (using glBlend), it is advised to sort objects from back to front z order.

From [opengl docs](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm):
When using depth buffering in an application, you need to be careful about the order in which you render primitives. Fully opaque primitives need to be rendered first, followed by partially opaque primitives in back-to-front order. If you don't render primitives in this order, the primitives, which would otherwise be visible through a partially opaque primitive, might lose the depth test entirely.

So, whenever I'm rendering translucent objects after rendering opaque triangles, if I render translucent triangles from back to front in relation to the "view direction", is this correct? What exactly does back to front mean here? I'm trying to understand, if I have a scene objects that go through a mvp transformation, do I need to specifically look at the order in world coordinates, and in relation to the camera center?

Also, additionally does this change depending on the blend type?

Comment: this [OpenGL - How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214) might interests you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you render translucent triangles, you have to draw them back-to-front. Back-to-front here means, that you have to draw triangles first that are further away from the screen (that have a higher depth value).

The reason why this is necessary is that most blending equations yield different results depending on the order. The equations as implemented in OpenGL are usually such that they give "correct" results when rendering back-to-front.

Comment: Could you kindly go more into depth what back-to-front in relation to the screen means here? Specifically, in terms of camera center, and world coordinates. There's some detail that's missing in most explanations out there.

Comment: The definition is: From higher depth value to lower depth value. In world coordinates this means you have to draw objects first that are further away from the camera center.

Comment: @dev_nut it means you need to render the far most faces first in camera space (not in world space). With intersecting (semi)transparent polygons is this not an easy task.

Comment: @Spektre If the polygons intersect, then you need to subdivide them at the intersection. I guess if the geometry is static, this is not a problem, as subdivision can be done before rendering, but if it's some dynamic mesh, well, that will require some very good polygon processing logic.

Comment: @dev_nut yep exactly there are some workarounds however see the answers in the QA I linked in my comment bellow your question. Also in case you know you got just few layers of transparency you can remember few depth layers of rendering at runtime (depth sort fragments instead of polygons) and combine at the end (but that is really hard to implement on GPU) . I think the nVidia paper in one of the answers is your best choice in such cases if you do not want to turn to [ray tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214).

Answer (score 0):

I think the order matters not only because of the blending function you 
are using but one important aspect of pipeline you have to keep in mind. The z test happens before blending operation down the line in pipeline. 
Consider scenario where we are drawing two triangles t1 and t2 t1 is back of t2.

So If z test rejects all fragments belonging to t1 so no color value for t1 is written to color buffer. Now later on t2 fragments are being drawn which is exactly in front of t1 which z test rejected in last step. So ideally the colors of t1 would have been blended with colors of t2 but because of failed z test of t1 and blending operation being after z test t2 colors wont be blended.

Hence If you are not keeping order then disable z test and then draw your object with proper blending function. This is not so good in performance as lots of z tests will fail.

So you maintain order or polygons but this solution also doesnt scale with number of polygons increasing and when there is mixture of opaque and transparent objects.

Hence new solution is proposed of using order independent trasparency.
Different ways are there to implement this and you dont have to worry about order of objects.

I have implemented solution using per pixel linked list in fragment shader. You can find link below. This is not best solution but should give you fair idea.

[Order Independent Transparency](https://github.com/PixelClear/Order-Independent-Trasparency)