# OpenGL Make Texture Transparent VBO

Tags: opengl

I've been looking into how to make the bubble texture transparent but haven't found anything that would fit in my code. I have tried with `glColor4f()` but I might be putting it in the wrong place. I'm a total beginner in openGL and I've been given a basic code to which I need to add other objects in order to make a 2D scene. I also don't exactly know what every single line does.
These are the relevant pieces of code:

```cpp
// Globals
GLuint locT; // location of "T" uniform variable in myShaderProgram
GLuint locT2;


// Textures
GLuint myBubblesTexture = 0;

// Shader program object for applying textures to our shapes
GLuint myShaderProgram;

// Vertex Buffer Object IDs for the ground texture object
GLuint bubblesPosVBO, bubblesColourVBO, bubblesTexCoordVBO, bubblesIndicesVBO;


// 1) Position Array - Store vertices as (x,y) pairs
static GLfloat bubblesVertices[] = {

    -0.2f, -0.2f,
    -0.2f, 0.2f,
    0.2f, -0.2f,
    0.2f, 0.2f
};
// 2) Colour Array - Store RGB values as unsigned bytes
static GLubyte bubblesColors[] = {

    255, 0, 0, 255,
    255, 255, 0, 255,
    0, 255, 0, 255,
    0, 255, 255, 255

};
// 3) Texture coordinate array (store uv coordinates as floating point values)
static float bubblesTextureCoords[] = {

    0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f

};
// 4) Index Array - Store indices to quad vertices - this determines the order the vertices are to be processed
static GLubyte bubblesVertexIndices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };


void init(int argc, char* argv[]);
void setupBubblesTextureVBO(void);
void display(void);
void drawTexturedBubblesVBO(void);

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

    init(argc, argv);

    glutMainLoop();

    // Shut down COM
    shutdownCOM();

    return 0;
}


void init(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Initialise COM so we can use Windows Imaging Component
    initCOM();

    // Initialise FreeGLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(64, 64);
    glutCreateWindow("Funky Fish");

    // Register callback functions
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    // Initialise GLEW library
    GLenum err = glewInit();

    // Setup colour to clear the window
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.8f, 0.0f);
    glLineWidth(9.0f);

    //Load textures
    myBubblesTexture = fiLoadTextureA("bubbles.png");

    //Shader setup 
    myShaderProgram = setupShaders(string("Shaders\\basic_vertex_shader.txt"), string("Shaders\\basic_fragment_shader.txt"));

    // Get uniform location of "T" variable in shader program (we'll use this in the play function to give the uniform variable "T" a value)
    locT = glGetUniformLocation(myShaderProgram, "T");

    //Setup the bubbles using VBO
    setupBubblesTextureVBO();
}

// our bubbles
void setupBubblesTextureVBO(void) {

    // setup VBO for the quad object position data
    glGenBuffers(1, &bubblesPosVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesPosVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bubblesVertices), bubblesVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // setup VBO for the quad object colour data
    glGenBuffers(1, &bubblesColourVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesColourVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bubblesColors), bubblesColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // setup VBO for the quad object texture coord data
    glGenBuffers(1, &bubblesTexCoordVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesTexCoordVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bubblesTextureCoords), bubblesTextureCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // setup quad vertex index array
    glGenBuffers(1, &bubblesIndicesVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesIndicesVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bubblesVertexIndices), bubblesVertexIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void display(void) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw our bubble
    drawTexturedBubblesVBO();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void drawTexturedBubblesVBO(void) {

    glUseProgram(myShaderProgram);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    // Move our bubble to the centre of the screen
    GUMatrix4 T = GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(locT, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&T);


    // Bind each vertex buffer and enable
    // The data is still stored in the GPU but we need to set it up (which also includes validation of the VBOs behind-the-scenes)

    // Bind texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myBubblesTexture);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(myShaderProgram, "texture"), 0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesPosVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesColourVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesTexCoordVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


    // Bind the index buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bubblesIndicesVBO);

    // Draw the object - same function call as used for vertex arrays but the last parameter is interpreted as an offset into the currently bound index buffer (set to 0 so we start drawing from the beginning of the buffer).
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)0);
    //  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // use to force disable our shaderprogram
    // glUseProgram(0);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks OK so:

- Does your Texture have an alpha channel?
- Does your **OpenGL** context pixel format has Alpha channel buffer?
- What kind of transparency you want (whole texture have the same transparency, or the transparency should be modulated)?

The  `glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,alpha)` will work only if your textures are configured to be modulated by `glColor` and have nonzero alpha channel set so you need to add:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
```

call after binding the texture to make it work.

In case you do not have alpha channel (in texture or in pixelformat) you can use:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

Also take a look at:

- [OpenGL - How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214)