# Transparency on certain objects only?

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency, alphablending

I have managed to get a transparent cube using

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

and in shader.frag:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(TextureMap_uniform, uv).xyz,0.5);
```

but now I would like the solid model I am moving around above the transparent cubes to be opaque (the transparency is applied to everything at the moment). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's the `0.5` in the `gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(TextureMap_uniform, uv).xyz,0.5);` which makes them half-transparent. Change that (e.g. using a uniform instead like recommended in the answer) to modify the transparency (0.0 -> invisible, 1.0 -> opaque).

Comment: Alternatively, you could `glDisable(GL_BLEND);` before rendering the cubes intended to be opaque. With disabled blending, the alpha value has no effect.

Comment: see [OpenGL - How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

are you using the same shader ?
if yes, then you will need to pass to your shader the information about opacity for each object.
a way to do that simply is by using uniform variables.

check out those links :

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glUniform

Comment: You just have earned your first 10 points rep. ;-) To improve the answer, you should cite the essence from the links. (Links may get lost and are not considered as that reliable to provide important info.)