# OpenGL Sphere Lighting/Transparency Problem

Tags: opengl

I am drawing a sphere but when I move the viewpoint it sometimes seen as I attached in the image. What may be the reason of it?

I thought it may be sth related with normals but could not find a solution.

Image That Shows Sphere:

[image: img]

Comment: You've to to draw the primitives in sorted order form the back to the front. Read [Transparency](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-10-transparency/)

Comment: what is the topology of your sphere? the parallel discs are hinting there is something fishy in your sphere mesh. Anyway with transparency you need depth sort your faces or fake it with other means see [OpenGL - How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214)

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove transparency at all?

Comment: `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` but my bet is that your mesh is wrong (wrongly triangulated connected as discs instead of surface) You can try this: [sphere triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214) anyway without MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example) we can only guess ...

Comment: Pretty late, Im sorry but you just need to enable BACKFACE_CULLING. glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) should take care of it.