# Transparent shape texture

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-compat

How can I make the texture of a shape transparent? (E.g. cube or cylinder).

I'm trying now:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 1f);
glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.2f);
//Cube code
```

This doesn’t work quite right, the textures are getting lighter, but I don’t see the objects behind them.

How can I make transparency, which will show what is behind the object?

Comment: Blending will not automatically get transparency right. You'll need to draw the objects  in the right order sorted from back to front to get correct transparency.

Comment: But remember that for depth-tested non-transparent drawing, front-to-back is the way to go, so don't do back-to-front for everything.

Comment: OpenGL transparency is tricky because OpenGL renders things *one at a time* - you tell it to draw some polygons on the screen, then some more polygons. If you draw transparent stuff before the stuff that comes behind it, while using a depth buffer, the depth buffer will make it so *only* the transparent stuff is drawn. If you draw the behind stuff before the transparent stuff, then they're both drawn.

Comment: see [OpenGL - How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214)