# OpenGL translucent quad artifact

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I am currently attempting to make my water texture translucent. I have added the following blending parameters:

```
void Application::initialiseOpenGL() {
  printf("Initialising OpenGL context\n");
  context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
  assertFatal(context != NULL, "%s\n", SDL_GetError());
  SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(0);
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  // glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  // glCullFace(GL_BACK);
}
```

My water looks fine from one side:
[image]

However, from the other side, it seems to overwrite already rendered quads:
[image]

This is what underwater looks like:
[image]

What could be the issue here?

These are my shaders:

```
#version 300 es
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in float vertexFaceIndex;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertexUV;

out float fragmentFaceIndex;
out vec2 fragmentUV;
out float visibility;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 viewProjection;
uniform float currentTime;

const float fogDensity = 0.005;
const float fogGradient = 5.0;

void main() {
  fragmentFaceIndex = vertexFaceIndex;
  fragmentUV = vertexUV;
  float distance = length(vec3(view * vec4(position, 1.0)));
  visibility = exp(-1.0f * pow(distance * fogDensity, fogGradient));
  visibility = clamp(visibility, 0.0, 1.0);
  if(vertexFaceIndex == 6.0f) {
    float yVal = position.y - 0.4 +
    min(0.12 * sin(position.x + currentTime / 1.8f) + 0.12 * sin(position.z + currentTime / 1.3f), 0.12);
    gl_Position = viewProjection * vec4(vec3(position.x, yVal, position.z), 1.0);
  }
  else
    gl_Position = viewProjection * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D atlas;
out vec4 color;

in float fragmentFaceIndex;
in vec2 fragmentUV;
in float visibility;

const float ambientStrength = 1.1f;
const float diffuseStrength = 0.3f;

const vec3 lightDirection = vec3(0.2f, -1.0f, 0.2f);
const vec4 skyColor = vec4(0.612, 0.753, 0.98, 1.0);
const vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0f, 0.996f, 0.937f);
const vec3 ambientColor = lightColor * ambientStrength;
// Face normals have been manually verified...
const vec3 faceNormals[7] = vec3[7](
  vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
  vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),
  vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
  vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
  vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
  vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
  vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
);

void main() {
  vec4 textureFragment = texture(atlas, fragmentUV).rgba;
  if(textureFragment.a < 0.5) discard;
  float diffuseFactor = max(dot(faceNormals[int(fragmentFaceIndex)], normalize(-1.0f * lightDirection)), 0.0) * diffuseStrength;
  vec3 diffuseColor = diffuseFactor * lightColor;
  color = vec4((ambientColor + diffuseColor) * textureFragment.rgb, textureFragment.a);
  color = mix(skyColor, color, visibility);
}
```

Comment: see [OpenGL - How to create Order Independent transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37783085/2521214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using this kind of polygonal rendering approach translucent polygon must be drawn last and in back-to-front order if there are multiple overlapping translucent polygons.

z-buffer is not enough to render correctly a scene that contains translucent polygons if you don't do this sorting.

The problem you are observing is because the water polygon is drawn first, and the block behind it is drawn later but no pixels are rendered because the z-buffer has already been set to the water level. Disabling z-buffer update when drawing the water wouldn't work either because in that case the under water block drawn later would appear in normal colors.

You need to draw water last.