# Efficiently rendering a transparent terrain in OpenGL

Tags: performance, opengl, transparency, terrain

I'm writing an OpenGL program that visualizes caves, so when I visualize the surface terrain I'd like to make it transparent, so you can see the caves below.  I'm assuming I can normalize the data from a Digital Elevation Model into a grid aligned to the X/Z axes with regular spacing, and render each grid cell as two triangles.  With an aligned grid I could avoid the cost of sorting when applying the painter's algorithm (to ensure proper transparency effects); instead I could just render the cells row by row, starting with the farthest row and the farthest cell of each row.

That's all well and good, but my question for OpenGL experts is, how could I draw the terrain most efficiently (and in a way that could scale to high resolution terrains) using OpenGL?  There must be a better way than calling `glDrawElements()` once for every grid cell.  Here are some ways I'm thinking about doing it (they involve features I haven't tried yet, that's why I'm asking the experts):

### `glMultiDrawElements` Idea

- Put all the terrain coordinates in a vertex buffer
- Put all the coordinate indices in an element buffer
- To draw, write the starting indices of each cell into an array in the desired order and call `glMultiDrawElements` with that array.

This seems pretty good, but I was wondering if there was any way I could avoid transferring an array of indices to the graphics card every frame, so I came up with the following idea:

### Uniform Buffer Idea

This seems like a backward way of using OpenGL, but just putting it out there...

- Put the terrain coordinates in a 2D array in a uniform buffer
- Put coordinate index offsets 0..5 in a vertex buffer (they would have to be floats, I know)
- call `glDrawArraysInstanced` - each instance will be one grid cell
- the vertex shader examines the position of the camera relative to the terrain and determines how to order the cells, mapping `gl_instanceId` to the index of the first coordinate of the cell in the Uniform Buffer, and setting `gl_Position` to the coordinate at this index + the index offset attribute

I figure there might be shiny new OpenGL 4.0 features I'm not aware of that would be more elegant than either of these approaches.  I'd appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glMultiDrawElements()` approach sounds very reasonable. I would implement that first, and use it as a baseline you can compare to if you try more complex approaches.

If you have a chance to make it faster will depend on whether the processing of draw calls is an important bottleneck in your rendering. Unless the triangles you render are very small, and/or your fragment shader very simple, there's a good chance that you will be limited by fragment processing anyway. If you have profiling tools that allow you to collect data and identify bottlenecks, you can be much more targeted in your optimization efforts. Of course there is always the low-tech approach: If making the window smaller improves your performance, chances are that you're mostly fragment limited.

Back to your question: Since you asked about shiny new GL4 features, another method you could check out is indirect rendering, using `glDrawElementsIndirect()`. Beyond being more flexible, the main difference to `glMultiDrawElements()` is that the parameters used for each draw, like the start index in your case, can be sourced from a buffer. This might prevent one copy if you map this buffer, and write the start indices directly to the buffer. You could even combine it with persistent buffer mapping (look up `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT`) so that you don't have to map and unmap the buffer each time.

Your uniform buffer idea sounds pretty interesting. I'm slightly skeptical that it will perform better, but that's just a feeling, and not based on any data or direct experience. So I think you absolutely should try it, and report back on how well it works!

Stretching the scope of your question some more, you could also look into approaches for order-independent transparency rendering if you haven't considered and rejected them already. For example alpha-to-coverage is very easy to implement, and almost free if you would be using MSAA anyway. It doesn't produce very high quality transparency effects based on my limited attempts, but it could be very attractive if it does the job for your use case. Another technique for order-independent transparency is depth peeling.

If some self promotion is acceptable, I wrote an overview of some transparency rendering methods in an earlier answer here: [OpenGL ES2 Alpha test problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280692/opengl-es2-alpha-test-problems/23283256#23283256).

Comment: Cool, you mentioned a lot of techniques I wasn't aware of (and thanks for the pointer to `glDrawElementsIndirect()`.  Depth peeling and alpha to coverage are neat, but I think I should probably just stick to a sort-based method.

Comment: So, I haven't tested the uniform buffer idea yet.  I got the `glMultiDrawElements()` approach to work, and there were no significant performance problems.  I'll try the uniform buffer approach later if I can find the time...