# Transparency does not work after vertex buffer changes in opengl

Tags: opengl, textures, transparency

I have grouped my rendering by Mesh->Material->GameObject. Unfortunately transparent textures will only let me see objects with the same mesh as the mesh the material with transparency is on. Do I have to render transparent textures first ? Or what's my mistake ?

Comment: Rendering correctly with transparency is difficult. You can sort all triangles in the scene and render them in the correct order or use a technique like depth peeling.

Comment: I wrote what's intended to be a fairly comprehensive overview of transparency rendering in another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280692/opengl-es2-alpha-test-problems/23283256#23283256. It might be helpful for you. Other than that, we would need more details about what exactly you're doing. I figure you're probably using blending to render the transparent objects?