# Using Depth test on transparent shapes in

Tags: opengl, alpha, blend, depth-buffer

I'm trying to use depth test and alpha-blend together. What I want to do is put an opaque small ring inside of a bigger and transparent one. I should enable depth testing in order to prevent bad geometry. so if I enable depth test I can't display inner ring. Is there a workaround for this issue. Thank you for help. My code is showed below:

```
   #include <GLTools.h> // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLMatrixStack.h>
#include <GLFrame.h>
#include <GLFrustum.h>
#include <GLGeometryTransform.h>
#include <GLShaderManager.h>
#include <math3d.h>

#include <math.h>
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL\glut.h>

GLFrame viewFrame;
GLFrustum viewFrustum;
GLBatch triangleBatch;
GLTriangleBatch torusBatch;
GLTriangleBatch torusBatch2;
GLMatrixStack modelViewMatrix;
GLMatrixStack projectionMatrix;
GLGeometryTransform transformPipeline;
GLShaderManager shaderManager;

// Flags for effects
bool iCull = true;
bool iDepth = true;

GLfloat blockSize = 0.3f;
GLfloat vVerts[] ={-blockSize, -blockSize, 0.0f,
                    blockSize, -blockSize, 0.0f,
                    blockSize, blockSize, 0.0f};

void ProcessMenu(int value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case 1:
            iDepth = !iDepth;
            break;

        case 2:
            iCull = !iCull;
            break;

        case 3:
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
            break;

        case 4:
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
            break;

        case 5:
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POINT);
            break;
        case 6:
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
            break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void bounceFunction(void)
{
    static GLfloat xDir = 1.0f;
    static GLfloat yDir = 1.0f;

    GLfloat stepSize = 0.0005f;

    GLfloat blockX = vVerts[0];   // Upper left X
    GLfloat blockY = vVerts[7];  // Upper left Y

    blockY += stepSize * yDir;
    blockX += stepSize * xDir;

    if(blockX < -1.0f) {                  blockX = -1.0f; xDir *= -1.0f; }
    if(blockX > (1.0f - blockSize * 2)) { blockX = 1.0f - blockSize * 2; xDir *= -1.0f; }
    if(blockY < -1.0f + blockSize * 2)  { blockY = -1.0f + blockSize * 2; yDir *= -1.0f; }
    if(blockY > 1.0f) {                   blockY = 1.0f; yDir *= -1.0f; }

    vVerts[0] = blockX;
    vVerts[1] = blockY - blockSize*2;

    vVerts[3] = blockX + blockSize*2;
    vVerts[4] = blockY - blockSize*2;

    vVerts[6] = blockX + blockSize*2;
    vVerts[7] = blockY;


}

void movementKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
    /*GLfloat stepSize = 0.025f;
    GLfloat blockX = vVerts[0];
    GLfloat blockY = vVerts[7];

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
        blockY += stepSize;
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
        blockY -= stepSize;
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        blockX -= stepSize;
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
        blockX += stepSize;

    //CollisonDetection

    if(blockX < -1.0f)                  blockX = -1.0f;
    if(blockX > (1.0f - blockSize * 2)) blockX = 1.0f - blockSize * 2;;
    if(blockY < -1.0f + blockSize * 2)  blockY = -1.0f + blockSize * 2;
    if(blockY > 1.0f)                   blockY = 1.0f;

    //CollisonDetection end

    //Recalculation
    vVerts[0] = blockX;
    vVerts[1] = blockY - blockSize*2;

    vVerts[3] = blockX + blockSize*2;
    vVerts[4] = blockY - blockSize*2;

    vVerts[6] = blockX + blockSize*2;
    vVerts[7] = blockY;

    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    glutPostRedisplay();*/
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
        viewFrame.RotateWorld(m3dDegToRad(-5.0), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
        viewFrame.RotateWorld(m3dDegToRad(5.0), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        viewFrame.RotateWorld(m3dDegToRad(-5.0), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
        viewFrame.RotateWorld(m3dDegToRad(5.0), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Refresh the Window
    glutPostRedisplay();

}

void changeSize(int w, int h)
{
    // Prevent a divide by zero
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    // Set Viewport to window dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    viewFrustum.SetPerspective(35.0f, float(w)/float(h), 1.0f, 100.0f);

    projectionMatrix.LoadMatrix(viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix());
    transformPipeline.SetMatrixStacks(modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
}

void renderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Turn culling on if flag is set
    if(iCull)
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    else
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Enable depth testing if flag is set
    if(iDepth)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    else
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix(viewFrame);
    glPolygonOffset(-1.0f, -1.0f);

    GLfloat vRed[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f};
    GLfloat vBlue[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f};

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_DEFAULT_LIGHT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewMatrix(), transformPipeline.GetProjectionMatrix(), vRed);
    torusBatch.Draw();



    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_DEFAULT_LIGHT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewMatrix(), transformPipeline.GetProjectionMatrix(), vBlue);
    torusBatch2.Draw();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void SetupRC()
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);//Backgroung color

    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();
    viewFrame.MoveForward(7.0f);
    gltMakeTorus(torusBatch, 1.0f, 0.25f, 52, 26);
    gltMakeTorus(torusBatch2, 0.95f, 0.1f, 52, 26);

    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(1280,720);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");


    GLenum err = glewInit();

    if(err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        //Error handling
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return -1;
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutSpecialFunc(movementKeys);

    // Create the Menu
    glutCreateMenu(ProcessMenu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Toggle depth test",1);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Toggle cull backface",2);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Set Fill Mode", 3);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Set Line Mode", 4);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Set Point Mode", 5);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Set Line Mode Back Face Culling", 6);

    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no simple solution without any compromises. I wrote an overview of some common transparency rendering methods in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23283256. You may want to start with the simple form of Depth Peeling, which is easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you enable depth testing with your opaque objects, then do back-to-front rending of transparent objects with OVER blending enabled.  Still, self-intersecting objects present a problem that requires further work. Unfortunately, transparency is not a "flip a bit and it works" feature in OpenGL.

Here is a good overview of recent techniques & ideas.  https://developer.nvidia.com/content/transparency-or-translucency-rendering