# Result difference between android virtual device and real device

Tags: android, opengl-es

Following code is drawing two different cube (red/green) on android studio with JNI using opengl-ES. On the virtual device, the result is correct. However, on real device, the result looks like strange. 
The structure(means 3d model and its view on 2d) is correct. but the color is different to AVD. In addition it looks like the depth test is not working. What's the problem?

Simply speaking,
AVD : gives correct result (red, green cube with depth test on with specific camera pose)
real device : gives strange result (same camera pose to AVD. but color is different. two green cubes are there. also depth test not working)

```
float color1[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
float color2[] = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

int mColorHandle1;
int mColorHandle2;
glViewport(0,1280,720,1280);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle1, color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], 1.0f);
glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, gTriangleVertices1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle2, color2[0], color2[1], color2[2], 1.0f);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, 36);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: the differences are not much may be you should try to run the same app on other real devices and observe the result not the virtual ones.

Comment: Could it be that desktop gives you pixel format of RGB 24 and the device uses RGB 565?

Comment: I found an answer. its due to JAVA code problem. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738586/opengl-depth-buffer-on-android